# Featured image size always cropped bottom

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, thumbnails

Good day!

I am  trying to add a featured image to my post but every time I add a featured image, the lower part gets cut off.

[image]

Original size is 300x300 pixels.

[image]
If the windows size gets changed, usually into a mobile window size, the whole featured image gets resized to its original size.

What is causing this? Thanks.

Comment: probably css. check if something is placed over your image

Comment: @Vishwa Where should I check? And what should I look for? Thanks

Comment: use your browser's inspector tool. inspect your image and nearby elements

Comment: @Vishwa I just did that. Found the class and tried to modify it but not working.

Comment: what've you found?

Comment: @Vishwa It is in a class medium_large. Tried modifying it but still not changing size.

Comment: sorry I can't help with just that. do you have a live url where I can see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93280/discussion-between-marvin-castro-and-vishwa).